# Approximation by smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to prove some properties of Sobolev spaces and it would help me a lot if the following statement was true.

Let $\space \Omega \subset {\mathbb{R}}^n$ be open, bounded, non-empty set and let $f \in C^k(\overline{\Omega})$,  i.e. $f \in C^k({\Omega})$ and all the partial derivatives up to order $\space k \in \mathbb{N}$ admit continuous extensions to $\overline{\Omega}$.

Then there is a sequence of functions $\left ( f_n \right  )_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\space C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ converging uniformly to $f$ on $\overline{\Omega}$ such that also all the partial derivatives of $f_n$ converge uniformly to the correspondent partial derivative of $f \space$.

Is it true? I struggle finding a proof.

Thank you.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is starlike, then dilations of $f$ would work.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't assume that Ω is starlike.

Comment: @zhw. Why would those dilations be $C^\infty$? (Maybe that's not what you meant by "work" - yes, one could  use dilations to construct the required approximating functions...)

Comment: Have you tried convolution with a suitable mollifier?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use mollifiers but with no success.

Comment: If $\Omega$ has a nice boundary, then you can extend $f$ to a $C^k$-function on $\mathbb R^n$, approximate there, and restrict back. I guess that Lipschitz boundary is okay but inward cusps are dangerous.